# How to Convert base64 data of tiff (String) to base64 data of png (String) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64

I am trying to convert base64 of tiff to  base64 of png in controller of Ruby on Rails.

But, failed...

my ruby code is

```
@png_de =Base64.strict_encode64(IO.read('..//test1234.tif', mode: 'rb') )
```

this code causes not display a png image but a load failed icon in chrome.

I don't know how to fix the above issue

Comment: Why `//`? Just `/` should be fine.

Comment: "Failed" is not a technical explanation. Did you get an error? Did you get unexpected output? Does that file have any data in it?

Comment: Converting a TIFF to a PNG involves a *lot more* than just "base64" encoding. You need an image conversion tool.

Comment: Have a look at RMagick / MiniMagick